# How to add a new entry in OpenLDAP using JXplorer?

Tags: openldap

I am using JXplorer as the browser for OpenLDAP. I have imported an LDIF file, but when I try to add a new entry to the directory then I get the following error:

`Because there is no schema currently published by the directory, adding a new entry is unavailable.`

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Get the server to publish its schema. Nothing you can do about it from the client end. Totally off-topic for SO.

Comment: Even if i dont try to import an LDIF file. I just try to create a new DN in JXPlorer. I am getting this exception:Mar 11, 2014 4:38:50 PM com.ca.commons.cbutil.CBUtility error
WARNING: error displayed to user: Unable to perform Read entry operation.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; rema
ining name 'dc=com'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3112)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)

Comment: So you can't read `dc=com`. Is it a real entry, or only part of the base DN for the DIT?

Comment: its a part of base dn. Cant we read it? What if i want to add another base DN such as dc=company,dc=com ?